# Is my plot wrong? This is a plot of auc against lambda

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to fit a logistic regression model using glmnet package. My data consists of 5 columns and 748 observations. I want to predict if blood donor will donate blood at a specific time.

Here is my code but the plot I create is a bit strange.

````
str(blood.donation)
names(blood.donation)
table(apply(X = blood.donation,MARGIN = 2,FUN = function(x) is.na(x)))
summary(blood.donation)
apply(blood.donation, 2, function(x) var(x))

y <- as.factor(blood.donation$whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007)
class(y)

bl.do.data <- model.matrix(y~., data = blood.donation)[,-5]
class(bl.do.data)
head(bl.do.data)

indices <- sample(nrow(blood.donation), 0.70 * nrow(blood.donation))
dim(blood.donation[indices,])

fit.bl.do <- cv.glmnet(bl.do.data[indices,], y[indices], type.measure = "auc", nfolds = 10, family = "binomial")
class(fit.bl.do)
plot(fit.bl.do)```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Unfortunately, the plot created is a bit strange. There is a straight line with variable numbers all equal to 1 above it.

Just wonder if I missed a step during my analysis


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DW7M.jpg

Here is my data

```head(blood.donation)
  Recency..months. Frequency..times. Monetary..c.c..blood. Time..months.
1                2                50                 12500            98
2                0                13                  3250            28
3                1                16                  4000            35
4                2                20                  5000            45
5                1                24                  6000            77
6                4                 4                  1000             4
  whether.he.she.donated.blood.in.March.2007
1                                          1
2                                          1
3                                          1
4                                          1
5                                          0
6                                          0```
````

Comment: Interesting question, but this is off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Also, you can help others help you by showing the plot instead of waiting for others to run the code, and by pointing out what is the aspect of the plot which seems strange to you.

Comment: To post your data use `dput(blood.donation)`. Don't use `header()`.